# Know if one of start urls is finished

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy and I want to scrape many urls, and my question is how can I know that scrapy changes to the second start urls.

`start_urls = ['link1', 'link2']`

Because I want to execute some code when scrapy switch from link1 to link2.

Thanks by advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `start_urls`, Scrapy automatically sends requests asynchronously, which means that callback for link2 may be invoked earlier than link1, so there's no "switching" between these links.

If you want to have these requests sent in a specific order, you can do the following:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    start_urls = [link1]

    def parse(response):
        # process response

        # execute the code you want to be between processing of link1 and link2

        yield Request(link2, self.parse)
```